# query to find the maximum gap between dates

Tags: sql, database, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with the name of each customer and date columns and want to write a query to give me the number of gap days for each user,

```
name date
ali 2022-01-01
ali 2022-01-04
ali 2022-01-05
ser 2022-03-01
```

the answer should be 3 for ali and for ser will be null.

here is what I tried:

```
select name ,min(date) over (partition by name order by date) start_date , max(date) over (partition by name order by date) end_date from table
```

Comment: 1) tag with dbms platform, 2) show your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to achieve this is using a window function (like lag, lead) to find the prior/next day and then find the difference between the dates (current and prior, for example ) using datediff function. Something like this..

```
SELECT name,
       MAX(datediff(date, PreviousDate)) AS Gap
FROM (SELECT name,
             date,
             LAG(date) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date) as PreviousDate
      FROM table t
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: quite elegant, however returns 0 for name 'ser' - OP wanted null instead

Comment: COALESCE was added to handle null values. If you want to see NULLS instead, you just need to remove it. Try the updated query.

Answer (score 1):

my approach is to match every record with the closest date then find the maximum gap and left join with the original table to get the gap for each user.

here's MySQL version:

```
select
    cu.name, max(cg.gap) maxgap
from
    customers cu left join
    (
    select
        c.name, datediff(min(cn.date), c.date) gap
    from
        customers c left join customers cn on c.name = cn.name
    where
        cn.date > c.date
    group by
        c.name, c.date
    ) cg
    on cu.name = cg.name
group by
    cu.name
```

Comment: for Ali, it should be 3 because, he was active at 1, 4, 5 and the maximum rage he was not active is between 1 and 4.

Comment: understood - I need to rebuild my sql then - what DBMS are you using - MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL, Oracle, other?

Comment: ok, posted final solution